# optimizing no. of queries being fired in django orm for a given model

Tags: python, django, profiling, django-queryset, django-orm

I have an object, that is uploaded by the user, it contains several details, but for the sake of clarity, can be simply defined by the following model representation -

After this other users can upvote and downvote what this user has uploaded hence a **vote model**.

Now I want to get the upvotes and downvotes of all the objects to be displayed in the template. Hence I add two functions to the `ObjectDetail` class, as upvote and downvote.

The trouble with this model is, say there are 20 objects, for each object 2 queries are fired one to get the upvote and the other to get the downvote. Hence the no. of queries are 40 now for 20 objects.

What would be a good way to tweak this to reduce the number of queries, and display the upvotes and downvotes on each of the object?

```
class ObjectDetail(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    img = models.ImageField()
    description = models.TextField()
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='voted_by')

    @property
    def upvote(self):
        upvote = Vote.objects.filter(shared_object__id = self.id, 
                             vote_type = True).count()
        return upvote

    @property
    def downvote(self):
        downvote = Vote.objects.filter(shared_object__id = self.id, 
                               vote_type = False).count()
        return downvote

class Vote(models.Model):
    vote_type = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    voted_by =  models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='voted_by')
    voted_for = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='voted_for')
    shared_object = models.ForeignKey(ObjectDetail, null=True, blank=True)
    dtobject  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On one hand, django does give you the capability to write raw SQL when you have to.  But this example is simple, you should not have to use raw SQL to get this information.

Django will put off making a query until you access the results of a queryset.  So you can try to compose the whole query using querysets and Q objects and then access the results on the composed query - this should trigger one DB query (or one per model, rather than one per instance) for all the results.

So, how to do that?  You want to get all the Vote records for a given set of ObjectDetail records.  I'm going to assume you have a list of ids of ObjectDetail records.

Unfortunately, your upvote and downvote properties return the result of "count" on their query sets.  This counts as an "access to the results" of the queryset produced by the "filter" call.  I would change those method definitions to refer to the backwards-relation object manager vote_set, like so:

```
@property
def upvote(self):
    answer = 0
    for vote in self.vote_set.all ():
        if vote.vote_type:
            answer += 1
    return answer

@property
def downvote(self):
    answer = 0
    for vote in self.vote_set.all ():
        if not vote.vote_type:
            answer += 1
    return answer
```

Note we just access the query set of votes for the current object.  At this stage, we are assuming that the orm can access the cached results.

Now, in the view and/or template, we want to assemble the big complex query.

My example is a functional view:

```
def home (request):

    # just assigning a constant list for simplicity.
    # Also was lazy and did 10 examples rather than 20.
    objids = [ 1, 5, 15, 23, 48, 52, 55, 58, 59, 60 ]

    # make a bunch of Q objects, one for each object id:
    q_objs = []
    for objid in objids:
        q_objs.append(Q(id__exact = objid))

    # 'or' them together into one big Q object.
    # There's probably a much nicer way to do this.
    big_q = q_objs[0]
    for q_obj in q_objs[1:]:
        big_q |= q_obj

    # Make another queryset that will ask for the Vote objects
    # along with the ObjectDetail objects.
    # Try commenting out this line and uncommenting the one below.
    the_objects = ObjectDetail.objects.filter(big_q).prefetch_related('vote_set')
    # the_objects = ObjectDetail.objects.filter(big_q)

    template = 'home.html'
    context = {
        'the_objects' : the_objects,
        }
    context_instance = RequestContext (request)
    return render_to_response (template, context, context_instance)
```

Here are some pointers to related documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Answer (score 0):

It's in the docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra
I am using the extra() clause to inject some raw sql here.

EDIT: this works with an app called 'vot' and at least Sqlite. Change the `vot_*` table names to your needs.

```
from django.db.models import Count

objects = ObjectDetail.objects.all().extra(
  select={ 'upvotes': '''SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vot_vote
                          WHERE vot_vote.shared_object_id = vot_objectdetail.id
                            AND vot_vote.vote_type = 1''',
         'downvotes': '''SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vot_vote
                          WHERE vot_vote.shared_object_id=vot_objectdetail.id
                            AND vot_vote.vote_type = 0'''})
```

Now each element in `objects` has a upvotes and downvotes property.

Comment: Yeah, this is good and resorting back to plain SQL is in most cases always the #1 in optimizing queries.

Comment: Now that I think about it... Yes. plain SQL is better. Because I think there's no nice "filter" method for annotated Count aggregations...

Comment: When dealing with an ORM you do the tradeoff, you get rid of writing tedious SQL queries but you gain an overhead in performance. If you want performance you have to do the work.

Comment: how will the `Count('vote')` get the upvotes for this object without any filtering?

Comment: similarly, how will the `downvote` will get its value? An extra filter has to be applied to both of them, right?

Comment: user1629366 - have a look at my edited answer. it should solve the problem.